# Web Config file to Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

My web app is deployed in Azure Portal. I want to remove entire web.config file from my solution and want to configure it in Azure. Is it possible to do it, if possible where do I need to give the values in azure of web config like appSettings, system.web, runtime in azure. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to do it, if possible where do I need to give the values in azure of web config like appSettings, system.web, runtime in azure.

Yes, we could config them with [App Service Editor (Preview)](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/App-Service-Editor). We could visit it from the following url. But It is also included in your solution in the azure.

```
https://{yourWebsiteName}.scm.azurewebsites.net/dev/wwwroot/web.config
```

We also could config sensitive info that don't want to include in the web.config with [Azure appsetting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure).

Comment: I have gone through the app service editor and what I basically understood that is web config can be edited in run time  but here it's not the scenario I would like to delete the web config file from my solution where  I will  configure it in azure portal and as development is going on I can add future settings to config file

Comment: Do you mind sharing idea why want to remove the web.config file? If we don't want to save the sensitive info in the web.config, we could set it in the Azure [WebApp appsetting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure).